# windows prevent app from accessing internet

Tags: security, windows-8, firewall

I bought a desktop password management application and I want to make sure it is secure and doesn't send any data to the developer.

So I want to block it from using the internet.

I am using Windows 8.

Any idea how can I prevent it from sending any data, just in case it wants to send?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-stop-a-program-from-gaining-unsolicited-internet-access-in-windows-7/).

I think it solves my issue